# Passing validation tests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm learning Rspec for Rails and looking for a way to ensure that simply creating a class instance without a name provided will not succeed. How can I make this test below pass by making changes to the Dog class code?

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :dog_name
end

describe Dog do
  it "requires a dog name to be created" do
    dog = Dog.new(dog_name: nil)
    expect(dog.save).to be_false
  end
end
```

It would also be helpful to know how to write another test to verify that when a dog_name is set that the record created successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend checking out the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem.  This would allow you to do these tests extremely easily.  With `shoulda-matchers`, your tests would be:

```
describe Dog do
  context 'validations' do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:dog_name) }
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I think the oddone is new to RSpec which means adding up another library to do the matchers for them skips the learning process.

Comment: Totally, but part of the learning process is learning how to not re-invent the wheel if gems are available.

Comment: These are controller specs. OP wants to test model.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your test. It should pass if your system is set up correctly. You'll need to share the error you're getting if you want help in understanding why it's currently failing.

As for testing for successful creation, you would need to provide more information about what you've tried or what reference you are using that you don't understand in order to meet the SO question quality requirements.

Comment: This is not an answer and belongs as a comment. An answer can almost never contain a direct question and still be a valid answer.

Comment: @Jhawins I would say the first paragraph qualifies as an answer, but I've updated the second paragraph to eliminate the question.

Answer (score -3):

```
describe Dog do
  it "requires a dog name to be created" do
    dog = Dog.create(dog_name: nil)
    expect(dog).to have(1).error_on(:dog_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: you should always give an explanation of your answer

Comment: @NARKOZ Please stop answering as well in that case.

Comment: @NARKOZ that's a pretty crappy way to go about Stack man. What's the point in answering then?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques there is a lot of good points here for and against code only answers. In this case I think you should have maybe made an effort to provide *some* explanation for your code. It might be useful for someone else in the future.